# How can I start a unit test for this method? iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing

I want to unit test a method in my record.m file.

```
-(void)displayVoucher:(NSArray *)json
{
for (NSInteger x = 0; x < json.count; x++) {
    if ([[[json objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"VoucherCode"] isEqualToString: [self.delegate getVoucherCode]]) {
        self.voucherlabel.text = [[json objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"VoucherTypeDesc"] ;
         [_voucherlabel sizeToFit];
        voucherDescription = [[json objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"VoucherTypeDesc"];
    }
}
}
```

I have declared record.h in my test file, and tried implementing this:

```
- (void)testExample
{
  NSArray *json = [[NSArray alloc]init];
  [displayVoucher:json]; <——— 
}
```

Now obviously, the above code is wrong. But I am fairly new to objc and am not sure how I am suppose to "call" the displayVoucher in record.m. Can someone guide me to how I can implement this test case? I have looked at other tutorials such as this [one](http://www.preeminent.org/steve/iOSTutorials/XCTest/). I think I've followed it pretty well but the code is not doing what I want with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ignoring the actual implementation of the method completely, you have one large mistake in your unit test. Every method in Objective-C must either be called on a Class or an instance of a Class. You are not attempting to do either (you just wrote the method name on its own inside square brackets `[displayVoucher:json];`).

Your method is defined as an instance method as denoted by the leading dash (-). (You can read more about that [here](http://www.kobold2d.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2654212)). So you must create an instance of your class to call it on. I will assume that your class is named `Record`. So your test would end up looking like this:

```
- (void)testExample
{
    Record *record = [[Record alloc] init];
    NSArray *json = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    [record displayVoucher:json];

    XCTAssertEqualObjects(record.voucherlabel.text, @"expected text");
}
```

The last line with XCTAssertEqualObjects shows how you probably want to assert that the method has done what you think it should do. The test will fail if it did not update the voucherlabel text correctly.

Comment: funny enough, I JUST saw the crucial mistake. Thank YOU!